# timestamp in dailylight savings time

Tags: php, time, timezone, dst

Anyone have a function to get a timestamp `time()` in daylight savings time? And possibly GMT+1 insted of GMT. I need it to display timestamps of comments made on my site.

Comment: What do you mean? A timestamp is just a timestamp, that's the number of seconds since Jan 1. 1970 - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time .

Comment: stupid of me. Damn.. cant delete it now with your comment :)

Comment: You will get some insightful answers, no need to delete it, just make more clear what you're looking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timestamps are the number of seconds elapsed since January 1st, 1970 GMT. That's a fixed number, not depending on whether you're saving daylight and independent of timezones. When you convert back to "human readable time", that's when your timezone and DST settings need to be taken into account. Set your timezone correctly or explicitly set a timezone on a DateTime object when formatting a timestamp to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

You should set your timezone to php setting. 
There are some ways to do it:

- [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/date_default_timezone_set) function
- [date.timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) ini setting

After that all time functions willl work in this timezone